# Confusion about maximum likelihood estimation of exponential distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood

The probability density function of the exponential distribution is defined as

$$
f(x;\lambda)=\begin{cases}
\lambda e^{-\lambda x} &\text{if } x \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x<0
\end{cases}
$$

We know that mle of the parameter $\lambda$ is $$\lambda = \frac{n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}$$ According to this solution, it seems $x \geq 0$ has no effect in the solution. My question is that why don't we use the constaint $x \geq 0$ in here? What happens when any of $x_i$'s less than zero?

Comment: none of the $X_i$ can be less than zero...

Comment: ... so $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$ cannot be less than $0$ and so $\hat \lambda$ will never be negative

Comment: @Henry, I would say the solution is max[$0$,$\frac{n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}$] but this approach allows some of $x_i$'s zeros. On the other hand, if any of $x_i$'s zero, then the likelihood will be directly zero.

Comment: When $x_i=0$, you have $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}=\lambda$ not $0$.  But according to your density $X_i<0$ with probability $0$ so really does not need to be covered

Comment: @Henry, sorry I should have said less than zero in my previous comment. So, is max[$0$,$\frac{n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}$] true?

Comment: There is zero probability $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i <0$, so you do not need to worry about it